# Youtube API: no way to get liked videos from user's activity feed

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

It's a known issue that Youtube API (v2) doesn't support liked videos - http://www.youtube.com/my_liked_videos (not http://www.youtube.com/my_favorites). The trick was to use events API for user's recent activity and filter out those with yt:rating.value = like. However, when I hit this endpoint https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/events?inline=true (with proper authorization headers), I only get last 24 events and all of them are of 'X has uploded a video' type. Has anyone experienced this and figured out what is wrong?

Comment: Are you sure there are _like_ activities in between? Did you try changing max-results/start-index parameters?

Comment: Yup, I tried max-results/start-index parameters, but the maximum it returned was 24, regardless.

Answer (score 5):

You can get liked videos without much effort in v3 of the API. I don't think there's a workaround for this in v2.

In v3, make a `channels.list(part=contentDetails)` call to get the "likes" playlist id, and then do a `playlistItems.list()` call to get the contents of that playlist, i.e. the videos that have been liked.

Comment: this is likes given to channel... not history of likes given by user.